# android rotate clockwise over then rotate aniclockwise back on its own axis

Tags: android, animation, rotation, repeat

How to rotate imageview clockwise 10degree ,

then the imageview animation stop (at 10degree) rotate back(aniclockwise) to 0 degree in repeate?

I just know how to rotate to 10 degree, but I don't know how to return back to 0 degree.

Thank you very much.

imageview 0 degree → 10 degree → 0 degree ( repeat)

```
   RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(x, y, 10f, 10f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(700);
    imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the repeat mode of animation.

```
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```